# What's the difference between identical(x, y) and isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))?

Tags: r, comparison, equality, built-in, floating-point-comparison

Is there any difference between testing `isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))` and `identical(x, y)`?

The help page says:

> Don't use 'all.equal' directly in 'if'
>    expressions — either use 'isTRUE(all.equal(....))' or
>   'identical' if appropriate.

but that "if appropriate" leaves me in doubt.  How do I decide which of the two is appropriate?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`all.equal` tests for near equality, while `identical` is more exact (e.g. it has no tolerance for differences, and it compares storage type).  From ?identical:

> The function ‘all.equal’ is also
>   sometimes used to test equality this
>   way, but was intended for something
>   different: it allows for small
>   differences in numeric results.

And one reason you would wrap `all.equal` in `isTRUE` is because `all.equal` will *report* differences rather than simply return `FALSE`.

Comment: thanks, 'no tolerance' was the key: `all.equal(8.0, 9.0, tolerance=1.0)`

Comment: Another example is that `identical()` will say ints and longs are different, even if they have the same value, whereas `all.equal()` will say they're equal.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to differences in numerical tolerance and comparison of storage mode, unlike `all.equal()`, `identical` also tests equality of associated environments.  Regular objects in R don't normally have associated environments -- they are most commonly associated with `function` and `formula` (and `terms`) objects.  But to illustrate, I'll give two trivial objects different (newly created) environments:

```
x <- 2; environment(x) <- new.env()
y <- 2; environment(y) <- new.env()
all.equal(x,y)   ## TRUE
identical(x,y)   ## FALSE
```

There is an `ignore.environment` argument:

> ignore.environment: logical indicating if their environments should be ignored when comparing closures.

but since it is only applied when comparing closures (i.e. functions), it doesn't make a difference in this case - nor will it make a difference when comparing formulae or terms objects.

Answer (score 19):

`identical` is fussier. For example:

```
> identical(as.double(8), as.integer(8))
[1] FALSE
> all.equal(as.double(8), as.integer(8))
[1] TRUE
> as.double(8) == as.integer(8)
[1] TRUE
```