# Compare if two dataframe objects in R are equal?

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, equality

How do I check if two objects, e.g. dataframes, are value equal in R?

By value equal, I mean the value of each row of each column of one dataframe is equal to the value of the corresponding row and column in the second dataframe.

Comment: `?all.equal` or `?identical`?  If its not those two then you'll have to expand on your question so we know what exactly you're trying to compare.

Comment: Have a look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395696/difference-in-r-between-identicalx-y-and-istrueall-equalx-y)

Comment: what do you mean by "value equal"

Comment: I voted to close because it is too vague to answer in its current state.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It is not clear what it means to test if two data frames are "value equal" but to test if the values are the same, here is an example of two non-identical dataframes with equal values:

```
a <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
b <- data.frame(y = 1:10)
```

To test if all values are equal:

```
all(a == b) # TRUE
```

To test if objects are identical (they are not, they have different column names):

```
identical(a,b) # FALSE: class, colnames, rownames must all match.
```

Comment: In case anyone's confused, they aren't identical because the column names aren't the same.

Comment: @joran thanks for pointing that out, I have clarified my answer.

Comment: Note that for `identical` to return true not just values and column names must match, but row numbers/names too. (This hit me when using subset(); it turned out `all` was what I wanted.)

Comment: @DavidLeBauer is there a way to make identical ignore the order?

Comment: @user4050 the order of what? the order of values? You could sort both vectors like `identical(sort(a), sort(b))`.

Answer (score 14):

In addition, identical is still useful and supports the practical goal:

```
identical(a[, "x"], b[, "y"]) # TRUE
```

Answer (score 9):

We can use the R package `compare` to test whether the names of the object and the values are the same, in just one step.

```
a <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
b <- data.frame(y = 1:10)

library(compare)
compare(a, b)
#FALSE [TRUE]#objects are not identical (different names), but values are the same.
```

In case we only care about equality of the values, we can set `ignoreNames=TRUE`

```
compare(a, b, ignoreNames=T)
#TRUE
#  dropped names
```

The package has additional interesting functions such as `compareEqual` and `compareIdentical`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method using `comparedf` from the `arsenal` package.

It gives you the differences detected by variable, the variables not shared (different columns, for example), the number of observations not share as well as a summary of the overall comparison.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = paste0("person", 1:3),
                  a = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  b = c(1, 3, 4))

> df1
         id     a       b 
1     person1   a       1 
2     person2   b       3
3     person3   c       4


df2 <- data.frame(id = paste0("person", 4:1),
                  a = c("c", "b", "a", "f"),
                  b = c(1, 3, 4, 4),
                  d = paste0("rn", 1:4))

> df2

        id     a     b     d

1     person4  c     1    rn1
2     person3  b     3    rn2
3     person2  a     4    rn3
4     person1  f     4    rn4


library(arsenal)
comparedf(df1, df2)

Compare Object
Function Call: 
comparedf(x = df1, y = df2)

Shared: 3 non-by variables and 3 observations.
Not shared: 1 variables and 0 observations.

Differences found in 2/3 variables compared.
0 variables compared have non-identical attributes.
```

There is a possibility to get a more detailed `summary`.

```
 summary(comparedf(df1, df2))
```

The code below will return several tables:

- Summary of data.frames
- Summary of overall comparison
- Variables not shared
- Other variables not compared
- Observations not shared
- Differences detected by variable
- Differences detected
- Non-identical attributes

Here you have [more info](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arsenal/vignettes/comparedf.html) about the package and the function.

Additionally, you can use `all.equal(df1, df2)` too.

```
[1] "Attributes: < Component “row.names”: Numeric: lengths (3, 4) differ >"
[2] "Length mismatch: comparison on first 3 components"                    
[3] "Component “id”: Lengths (3, 4) differ (string compare on first 3)"    
[4] "Component “id”: 3 string mismatches"                                  
[5] "Component “a”: Lengths (3, 4) differ (string compare on first 3)"     
[6] "Component “a”: 2 string mismatches"                                   
[7] "Component “b”: Numeric: lengths (3, 4) differ"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the need to rely on another package, but to compare structure (class and attributes) of two data sets:

```
structure_df1 <- sapply(df1, function(x) paste(class(x), attributes(x), collapse = ""))
structure_df2 <- sapply(df2, function(x) paste(class(x), attributes(x), collapse = ""))

all(structure_df1 == structure_df2)
```