# different number of column name in selectIput Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have one problem with create dynamic UI (`selectInput`). I mean, I have two `dataframes` and one `selectInput` button which should change number of output (column name) depending on dataframe which I choose.
I just get error: `Error: == only defined for equally-sized data frames` when I choose `df2` dataframe. Could anyone tell me what I do wrong? 
This is my `if` function:

```
  output$xvars <- renderUI({
    if (datasetInput() == df1){
      axis_vars_x <- colnames(df1[c(1,2)])
      selectInput("xvar", "X-axis variable", axis_vars_x, selected = "id")
    }
    else{
      axis_vars_x <- colnames(df2[1])
      selectInput("xvar", "X-axis variable", axis_vars_x, selected = "id")
    }
  })
```

**ui.R**

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(
  radioButtons("dataset", label = h4("Product level"),
               choices = list("Item" = "df1", "Task" = "df2")),
  uiOutput("xvars"),
  ),
 mainPanel(
  ggvisOutput("plot")
  )
 )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), number = c(20,30,23,25,34), ds =  c(1,2,3,42,2))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), number = c(33,40), ds = c(1,2))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 datasetInput <- reactive({
  switch(input$dataset,
         df1 = df1,
         df2 = df2)
 })

 output$xvars <- renderUI({
    if (datasetInput() == df1){
      axis_vars_x <- colnames(df1[c(1,2)])
      selectInput("xvar", "X-axis variable", axis_vars_x, selected = "id")
    }
    else{
      axis_vars_x <- colnames(df2[1])
      selectInput("xvar", "X-axis variable", axis_vars_x, selected = "id")
    }
  })

 data <- reactive({
 df <- datasetInput()
 })

vis <- reactive({
 data %>%
  ggvis(~id, ~number) %>%
  layer_points(fill = ~factor(id)) %>%
  scale_nominal("fill", range = c("red","blue","green","yellow","black"))

})
vis %>% bind_shiny("plot")
})
```

Comment: use `identical(df1,datasetInput())`, instead of '==' see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592148/compare-if-two-objects-in-r-are-equal)

Comment: also you code doesn't run as is, you have an extra comma after `uiOutput("xvars")`...

Comment: OK thanks once again! I wondering how to use it to manipulate y-axis. I mean, instead of `axis_vars_x <- colnames(df1[c(1,2)])`  I use `axis_vars_x <- colnames(df1[c(2,3)])` to get numeric values. How to change y-axis depending on my choice in `selectInput`. Also use `if(!is.null(input$xvar))`  concept and then `var <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$xvar))`?

Comment: @NicE Could you tell me how introduce this variable to the `output` result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you comments, I assumed you wanted to change the y-axis to whatever was selected in the `selectInput` boxes. To do this with `ggvis` you need to change the data you pass to the plot.
You can try the following code, I changed a few of your variables:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), number = c(20,30,23,25,34), ds =  c(1,2,3,42,2))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), number = c(33,40), ds = c(1,2))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "df1" = df1,
           "df2" = df2)
  })

  output$yvars <- renderUI({
    if (identical(df1,datasetInput())){
      axis_vars_y <- colnames(df1[-1])
      selectInput("yvar", "X-axis variable", axis_vars_y, selected = "id")
    }
    else{
      axis_vars_y <- colnames(df2[-1])
      selectInput("yvar", "X-axis variable", axis_vars_y, selected = "id")
    }
  })

  yVarName<-reactive({
    yValue<-"number"
    if(!is.null(input$yvar)){
      yValue<-input$yvar
    }
    yValue
  })

  data <- reactive({
    df<-datasetInput()
    yValue<-"number"
    if(!is.null(input$yvar)){
      yValue<-input$yvar
    }
    df <- datasetInput()[,c("id",yValue)]
    names(df)<-c("id","yVar")
    df
  })


  vis <- reactive({

    data %>%
      ggvis(~id, ~yVar) %>%
      layer_points(fill = ~factor(id)) %>%
      scale_nominal("fill", range = c("red","blue","green","yellow","black")) %>%
      add_axis("y", title = yVarName())

  })
  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot")
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("dataset", label = h4("Product level"),
                   choices = list("Item" = "df1", "Task" = "df2")),
      uiOutput("yvars")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      ggvisOutput("plot")
    )
  )
))
```