# different number of column name and different sliderInput Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem with my Shiny app. I mean, I want to have a dynamic ui `selectInput` which change number of column name like in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432863/different-number-of-column-name-in-selectiput-shiny) when I change a `dataframe`. But I also implement a solution in which `sliderInput` will also change depend on what I choose in `selectInput`. My code is [here](https://gist.github.com/Nicolabo/c20502d33dee37342b2d).

Comment: 1) There seem to be some minor mistakes, like taking into account NULL when you use switch and so on.. 2) You can dynamically create the slider as you have and then simply update it with updateSliderInput, you can put it into an observe statement.

Comment: @pops I've just updated the code a little. Could you expain when I should use `updateSliderInput`?