# How to compare a data frame with another data frame?

Tags: r

I've got a Data Frame (df) with 4 Columns and n rows

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L), y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), pch = c(9L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 12L, 9L, 
7L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 5L), col = c(7L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))

    x y pch col
1   1 1   9   7
2   2 1  10   8
3   3 1  11   3
4   4 1   7   3
5   5 1  12   4
6   6 1   9   6
7   7 1   7   3
8   8 1   5   4
9   9 1   8   2
10 10 1   1   1
11 11 1   8   7
12 12 1   2   5
13 13 1   5   4
14  1 2   8   7
15  2 2   5   6
```

and I want to compare the X and Y with another Data Frame 1x1 (df2)

```
df2 <- structure(list(V1 = 7, V2 = 1), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))

  V1 V2
1  7  1
```

and if it is the same I want to take the entry( in this case number 7) to draw it into my grid with the pch and col which are written in the first Data Frame.

My attempt was compare it with a if loop but I don't know how to get the right column from the first Data frame. In this case x = 7 y = 1 pch = 7 and col = 3

if(input$V1 == playfield$x && input$V2 == playfield$y)
{

}

Appreciate every help or idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare if two dataframe objects in R are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592148/compare-if-two-dataframe-objects-in-r-are-equal)

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
new_df <- playfield[playfield$x == input$V1 & playfield$y == input$V2,]
```

Comment: thanks for the input, gonna take a look at it, but I have an idea on how to work with that

Answer (score 1):

You could use `right_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

right_join(df, df2, by=c("x"="V1", "y"="V2"))
```

output:

```
  x y pch col
1 7 1   7   3
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L), y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), pch = c(9L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 12L, 9L, 
7L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 5L), col = c(7L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = 7, V2 = 1), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: thanks aswell, gonna take a look on the dplyr package and your solution aswell