# Why aren't these two R objects identical?

Tags: r

I was reading the book 'Data Mining with R' and came across this code:

```
library(DMwR)

clean.algae <- knnImputation(algae, k = 10)
x <- sapply(names(clean.algae)[12:18],
            function(x,names.attrs) {
              f <- as.formula(paste(x,"~ ."))
              dataset(f,clean.algae[,c(names.attrs,x)],x)
            },
            names(clean.algae)[1:11])
```

I thought `x` could be rewritten as:

```
y <- sapply(names(clean.algae)[12:18],
            function(x) {
              f <- as.formula(paste(x,"~ ."))
              dataset(f,clean.algae[,c(names(clean.algae)[1:11],x)],x)
            }
)
```

However, `identical(x,y)` returns `FALSE`.

I decided to investigate why by restricting my attention to just the first element these lists.

I found that:

```
identical(attributes(x[[1]])$data,
          attributes(y[[1]])$data)
[1] FALSE
```

However:

```
which(!(attributes(x[[1]])$data == attributes(y[[1]])$data))
integer(0)
```

Which to me means all elements in the data frame are equal, hence the two data frames must be identical. Why is this not the case?

I also have similar question for the object's formula attribute:

```
> identical(attributes(x[[1]])$formula,
+           attributes(y[[1]])$formula)
[1] FALSE
> 
> attributes(x[[1]])$formula == attributes(y[[1]])$formula
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Take a look at the difference between `identical` and `all.equal` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395696/difference-in-r-between-identicalx-y-and-istrueall-equalx-y) and read up on `?Comparison`.

Comment: not reproducible; how do we construct `clean.algae`, please? One thing to keep in mind is that `identical` presumably pays attention to environments, while `all.equal` wouldn't (I think).

Comment: @BenBolker I apologise. I've updated the code snippet to make it reproducible. It does not look to me that the data frame have anything to do with environments. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** the source of the non-identicality is indeed in differences in associated environments, both of the `@formula` slots of the components of the objects, and in the `terms` attributes of the `@data` slots.  As @ThomasK points out in comments above, for most comparison purposes `all.equal()` is good enough/preferred ...

Formulas are equal but not identical:

```
identical(x$a1@formula,y$a1@formula)
## [1] FALSE
all.equal(x$a1@formula,y$a1@formula)
## TRUE
```

Environments differ:

```
environment(x$a1@formula)
## <environment: 0x9a408dc>
environment(y$a1@formula)
## <environment: 0x9564aa4>
```

Setting the environments to be identical makes the formulae identical:

```
environment(x$a1@formula) <- .GlobalEnv
environment(y$a1@formula) <- .GlobalEnv
identical(x$a1@formula,y$a1@formula)
## TRUE
```

However, there's more stuff that's different: `identical(x$a1,y$a1)` is still FALSE.

Digging some more:

```
for (i in slotNames(x$a1))  {
    print(i)
    print(identical(slot(x$a1,i),slot(y$a1,i)))
}
## [1] "data"
## [1] FALSE
## [1] "name"
## [1] TRUE
## [1] "formula"
## [1] TRUE
```

Digging deeper into the `data` slot (also with judicious use of `str()`) finds more environments -- associated with terms (closely related to formulae) this time:

```
dx <- x$a1@data
dy <- y$a1@data
environment(attr(dx,"terms"))
## <environment: 0x9a408dc>
environment(attr(dy,"terms"))
## <environment: 0x9564aa4>
```

Setting these equal to each other should lead to identicality between `x$a1` and `y$a1`, but I haven't tested.