# How to check if elements in one vector are equal to another vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, equality

I have two unequal vectors

```
x <- c(5,5,5,5,5,5)
y <- c(5,5)
```

I want to check if all elements in x is equal to all elements in y.

I tried `if(mean(x) - mean(y) == 0 & sd(x) - sd(y) ==0){count=count+1}`
However, I realized that some unique combination of elements can have same mean for x and y, and identical standard deviation. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this ?

Comment: do you just want `identical(x, y)` or `all.equal(x, y)` ?

Comment: can I please know what the difference is?

Comment: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3395696/5977215)

Comment: What about `length(setdiff(x, y)) == 0` this will work for non equal length and multiple distinct elements?

Comment: Can you include a complete example? For this `all(unique(x) %in% unique(y))` seem to work.

Comment: @RonakShah, that code works for this example, but not when vectors have dissimilarity. For that, you need a logical test.

Comment: `identical(sort(unique(x)), sort(unique(y)))`

Comment: This seems to do the job. It would be helpful if you could explain what sort is doing here

Comment: @biogeek, try running `?sort()` in your R console. It a function in base R. The documentation you can find when enter `?sort()` says: **"Sort (or order) a vector or factor (partially) into ascending or descending order."** It's basically sorting all unique values of x and y into a vector. Then with `identical()`, we ask if those vectors are exactly the same. If they are, then it stands to reason that all of the values in x are also in y.

Answer (score 2):

**Use a logical test on all unique values**:

```
x <- c(5,5,5,5,5,5)
y <- c(5,5)
z <- c(3,5,5)

> ifelse(unique(x) == unique(y), TRUE, FALSE)
[1] TRUE

> ifelse(unique(x) == unique(z), TRUE, FALSE)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

**If you want only one output, use `all()`, which returns TRUE if all values are TRUE:**

```
> all(ifelse(unique(x) == unique(y), TRUE, FALSE))
[1] TRUE

> all(ifelse(unique(x) == unique(z), TRUE, FALSE))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I'm trying to use `count = count +1` and so I tried to do `if(unique(x) == unique(y)){count=count+1}` followed but another else condition that is part of my larger code. But I keep running into an error that says `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: `count` in the dplyr package? I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but to the problem you posed, the solutions above work, as does @d.b.'s solution: `identical(sort(unique(x)), sort(unique(y)))`