# Check table's header is as expected when read.csv in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to insert a check step in my R script to determine if the structure of the CSV table I'm reading is as expected. 
See details:
table.csv has the following colnames:
[1] "A","B","C","D"

This file is generated by someone else, hence I'd like to make sure at beginning of my script that the colnames and the number/order of columns has not change.

I tried to do the following:

```
    #dataframes to import
    df_table <- read.csv('table.csv')

    #define correct structure of file
    Correct_Columns <- c('A','B','C','D')
    #read current structure of table
    Current_Columns <- colnames(df_table)

    #Check whether CSV was correctly imported from Source
    if(Current_Columns != Correct_Columns)

    {
    # if structure has changed, stop the script. 
    stop('Imported CSV has a different structure, please review export from Source.')
    } 
    #if not, continue with the rest of the script...
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think you want `if(any(Current_Columns != Correct_Columns))`. I assume you were getting some error before? It would be help to include the information about why your solution didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R, I suggest you take a look at `all.equal()`, `identical()` or `any()`.

See the following example:

```
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(1,2)
c <- c(1,2)
d <- c(1,2)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

names.df <- colnames(df)
names.check <- c("a","b","c","d")

!all.equal(names.df,names.check)
# [1] FALSE

!identical(names.df,names.check)
# [1] FALSE

any(names.df!=names.check)
# [1] FALSE
```

Following, your code could be modified as follows:

```
if(!all.equal(Current_Columns,Correct_Columns))
{
# call your stop statement here
}
```

Your code probably throws a warning because `Current_Columns!=Correct_Columns` will compare all entries of the vector (i.e. running `Current_Columns!=Correct_Columns` on its own on the console will return a vector with TRUE/FALSE values).

Contrary, `all.equal()` or `identical()` will compare the whole vectors while treating them as objects.

For the sake of completeness, please be aware of the slight difference between `all.equal()` and `identical()`. In your case it doesn't matter which one you use but it can get important when dealing with numerical vectors. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395696/whats-the-difference-in-r-between-identicalx-y-and-istrueall-equalx-y) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm! 
Only issue now is that it won't work when I recall the script from a master script:
        > #### Run script ####
        > source('location/...[TRUNCATED] 
        Error in eval(ei, envir) : 
        Imported CSV has a different structure, please review export from Source.

Comment: Almost forgot, if I run the very same script by itself, it works, and the IF instance does not trigger because file structure is actually the same. Only when I run it from the master script it fails the IF test...

Comment: I guess the code of your master script would be necessary to see where the bug is. My first guess would be that your working directory is a different one when running the master script and therefore a different "table.csv" file is loaded. But thats no more than a wild guess at this point.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("table.csv")
Correct_Columns <- c('A','B','C','D')
Current_Columns <- colnames(df_table)
```

Check if there is a false in pairwise matching:

```
if(F %in% Current_Columns == Correct_Columns){
  stop('Imported CSV has a different structure, please review export from Source.')
}
```

}