# R: Determining whether data frames in a list are identical

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

With a function f

```
f <- function(x) { data.frame(a=c(x, 2*x), b=c(2*x, 4*x)) }
```

we can construct two data frames

```
df1 <- f(5)
df2 <- f(5)
```

and want to confirm that they they are equal. Because we [ultimately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3396068/9295807) want to obtain a Boolean, we use `identical`, and indeed

```
identical(df1, df2)
```

evaluates to TRUE.

Now we compute three terms

```
terms <- lapply(rep(5, 3), f)
```

and want to determine whether the three data frames are equal. We choose to compare with the first term

```
first.term <- terms[1]
```

and evaluate

```
lapply(terms,
       function(x) identical(x, first.term))
```

but we get three FALSEs, not three TRUEs. What am I missing?

Comment: Use `first.term <- terms[[1]]`

Comment: `all(sapply(terms, identical, terms[[1]]))`

Comment: @markus Please add your comment as an answer, then I'll roll back the update and accept that answer. As it is there are two questions, and the present answer satisfies neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in OP's code was the use of `` `[` `` instead of `` `[[` ``. The former returns a list containing a `data.frame` while the latter returns that `data.frame`.

```
first.term <- terms[[1]]
lapply(terms, function(x) identical(x, first.term))
#[[1]]
#[1] TRUE
#
#[[2]]
#[1] TRUE
#
#[[3]]
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

To check for every combination of `data.frame`s in `terms`

```
apply(combn(length(terms), 2), 2, function(x)
    all.equal(terms[[x[1]]], terms[[x[2]]]))
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

To return whether *all* `data.frame`s in `terms` are identical

```
all(apply(combn(length(terms), 2), 2, function(x)
    all.equal(terms[[x[1]]], terms[[x[2]]])))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Cool, but doesn't the use of `combn` provide a solution that takes O(n^2) for a problem that is O(n)?

Comment: @Vrokipal, the problem is not O(n).... You need to compare the first data.frame with `n - 1` data.frames, the second with `n - 2`, etc.  giving `n * (n - 1) / 2` comparisons

Comment: @Emil Can you provide any input in R for which the result of the expression ((a == b) & (a == c)) is not the same as ((a == b) & (a == c) & (b == c))? Here a, b, and c can be anything you want, not just data frames. For each type we'd use the appropriate comparison operator; hence for data frames we'd use `identical`, not `==`.

Comment: @Vrokipal Yes the problem is `O(n^2)` if you check for all combinations. If you only compare to the first (like you mention in your post) it's `O(n)`. You already got the solution for the latter approach: `all(sapply(terms, function(x) all.equal(x, terms[[1]])))`

Comment: @Emil I'll take a stab answering my own question (the one in the comment). If we do a fuzzy comparison of data frames using `all.equal`, then the two terms do not yield the same result. It may well be that a is close to both b and c, but b and c are not within an acceptable threshold of each other.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I think you misunderstood why the OP says the problem is O(n). Using the associative property, it is only necessary to compare one element to the rest of the list. Comparing every possible combination creates many unnecessary checks. For example, with a collection of five, say `{a, b, c, d, e}`, one only needs 4 comparisons to determine if all elements are the same, not `choose(5, 2) = 10`.

Comment: @Emil Yes thanks for the clarification; I'm clear on the `O(n)` complexity, and that comparing to the first element suffices;-) OP already has an answer for that which I reiterated in my previous comment. In a wider context, performing all pairwise comparisons (which as you showed will be `O(n^2)`) might be useful to explore similarities between subsets of elements. I agree that this might go beyond what OP is after. That's why my first sentence of my answers starts with "To check for every combination ...".

Comment: @MauritsEvers, my mistake... I see where you are getting at now.

Comment: @Emil absolutely no need to apologise. I appreciate your clarification!