# Strange behaviour of == with formula

Tags: r, statistics, formula, logical-operators

I am a bit puzzled by the following. I have two formulas and would like to check whether they are the same. Here I expect to get FALSE returned.

```r
fm1 <- formula(schades ~ termijn + zipcode + provincie + regionvormgemeente + energielabel + trede)
fm2 <- formula(schades ~ termijn + zipcode + provincie + regionvormgemeente + energielabel)
fm1 == fm2
#> [1] TRUE

identical(fm1, fm2)
#> [1] FALSE
```

What is the reason that `fm1 == fm2` returns TRUE?

<sup>Created on 2021-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between identical(x, y) and isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395696/whats-the-difference-between-identicalx-y-and-istrueall-equalx-y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` is designed to compare values in atomic vectors, not formulars.

Furthermore, see the following example from `?==` :

```
x1 <- 0.5 - 0.3
x2 <- 0.3 - 0.1
x1 == x2                   # FALSE on most machines
isTRUE(all.equal(x1, x2))  # TRUE everywhere
```

Applied to your example you can find:

```
    > fm1 <- formula(schades ~ termijn + zipcode + provincie + regionvormgemeente + energielabel + trede)
> fm2 <- formula(schades ~ termijn + zipcode + provincie + regionvormgemeente + energielabel)
> fm1 == fm2
[1] TRUE
> 
> all.equal(fm1, fm2)
[1] "formulas differ in contents"
> isTRUE(all.equal(fm1,fm2))
[1] FALSE
```

But apparently reducing the number of predictors returns the expected result. It just illustrates that `==` should not be used for this type of comparison as its behaviour is not coherent:

```
> fm1 <- formula(schades ~ termijn + zipcode + provincie)
> fm2 <- formula(schades ~ termijn + zipcode)
> fm1 == fm2
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(all.equal(fm1,fm2))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: It seem to be an issue that `==` gives unexpected (incorrect) answers. Perhaps would be better that r returns an error for this comparison

Answer (score 2):

From `?Comparison`/Details: *"...Language objects such as symbols and calls are deparsed to character strings before comparison..."*

So, what happens prior to comparing is:

```
deparsefm1 = deparse(fm1)
deparsefm2 = deparse(fm2)
```

and, then, the `deparse`d language objects are compared.

The interesting thing here, though, is that R, internally, (i) selects only the first element of the deparsed object to proceed into comparison and (ii) does not, by default, use deparse options that limit the number of elements produced (while `deparse` offers that flexibility -- e.g. see how `deparse(fm1, 100) == deparse(fm2, 100)` behaves). So, while, we would expect

```
deparse(fm1) == deparse(fm2)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

we, actually, get

```
deparse(fm1)[[1]] == deparse(fm2)[[1]]
#[1] TRUE
```

I assume the "why that happens" is a good question.