# How to save a numerical matrix and restore it accurately?

Tags: r, matrix, read.table, write.table

I want to save a numerical matrix and then restore it accurately. But if I use identical() to compare the before- and after-saved matrices, they are not identical. I guess the problem is caused by floating point precision issues. How can I make the two matrices identical?

Thanks!

```
options(digits = 10)

data <-
  c(1 / 11, 1 / 22, 1 / 33, 1 / 44, 1 / 55, 1 / 66, 1 / 77, 1 / 88, 1 / 99) # Generate a numerical matrix.

x <- matrix(data,
            nrow = 3,
            ncol = 3,
            byrow = TRUE)

write.table(x, "test.csv") # Save the matrix.

y <- as.matrix(read.table("test.csv")) # Restore the matrix.

y <- unname(y) # Remove the attributes.

all.equal(x, y) # I got TRUE.

identical(x, y) # I got FALSE. How can I get TRUE here?

unlink("test.csv")
```

Comment: `all.equal` and `identical` are different things: 
`all.equal` tests for near equality, while `identical` is more exact (e.g. it has no tolerance for differences, and it compares storage type). See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395696/whats-the-difference-between-identicalx-y-and-istrueall-equalx-y>

Comment: You will also lose precision when “printing” to csv. What do you see if you save with `saveRDS` and load with `readRDS`?

Comment: Wow. saveRDS() and readRDS() save me! I love them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all.equal` has a tolerance parameter whose default allows for the values being compared to be very near equal but not exactly so while `identical` requires exact equality.

If you'd like the restored file to be identical, you can save as an RDS rather than a csv. Saving as an RDS also preserved other attributes of an R object that saving as a csv does not, allowing you to avoid converting the object back to the desired type after read in.

```r
options(digits = 10)

data <-
  c(1 / 11, 1 / 22, 1 / 33, 1 / 44, 1 / 55, 1 / 66, 1 / 77, 1 / 88, 1 / 99) # Generate a numerical matrix.

x <- matrix(data,
            nrow = 3,
            ncol = 3,
            byrow = TRUE)

saveRDS(x, "test.RDS")

y <- readRDS( "test.RDS") # Restore the matrix.

all.equal(x, y) 
#> [1] TRUE

identical(x, y) 
#> [1] TRUE

unlink("test.RDS")
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the saved RDS file reduces my original 4GB csv file (a huge matrix) to only 1GB. This is so nice, in terms of disk space!