# function %in% gives an improper outcome

Tags: r

I'm making a program on R where I ask an input from the user which has to be a number between 0 and 100, with 2 decimals : seq(0, 100, 0.01) or 0:10000/100
Testing that :

```
TheAnswer %in% seq(0, 100, 0.01)
```

It was correct most of the time, but refused precise numbers (2.55, 3.55).
Simplifying the problem, I found this king of paradox :

```
> seq(1.6, 3.6, 0.05)[39]          
[1] 3.5
> seq(1.6, 3.6, 0.05)[39] == 3.5
[1] TRUE                            # runs normally
> seq(1.6, 3.6, 0.05)[40]
[1] 3.55
> seq(1.6, 3.6, 0.05)[40] == 3.55
[1] FALSE                           # It perfectly finds 3.55 at position 40, but tells me it's not equal to it
```

Same problem if I use 0:10000/100
Restarting R didn t change it.
It disappears if I reduce the range or if I ask a slightly different number (3.54, 3.56).

Thank you for your time,
Benoît

Comment: Sounds like a classic [floating point issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)?

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395696/whats-the-difference-between-identicalx-y-and-istrueall-equalx-y and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems to be the explanation, I'll try to work it out. Thanks for the quickness <3 :)